# Spring boot + Maven project not start with mvnw command, but runs work on Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am building a project in Spring Boot + Maven. I have a main project "Entry" which receives the HTTP calls in the Controller classes. It then delegates the responsibility to an application layer that is in the “module” folder. Created a module for it.
It turns out that from the Intellij the project starts correctly and works fine. But when I try to boot it with the maven command (mvnw spring-boot:run) I get an error. He tried a thousand touch-ups and he was already exhausted. Not be what else to do. If someone can help me.

Source: https://github.com/efimatica/demo-business

Running on Intellij
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJOkH.png)

Send a request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeNEu.png)

Running on Terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQD0N.png)

Thank you

Comment: The source code on the root level does not make sense because the root pom is if packaging: pom which means the code will not being compiled etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your suggestion. I've restructured creating one root pom and two modules. Now the compilation runs right and I can create an operable Jar. Howerver the spring-boot:run doesn't start. I've read that can't use spring-boot:run in multiple module project, it's truth?